# What first century Jews were claimed to have risen from the dead?

Tags: resurrection

Which first century Jews have been claimed to have been risen from the dead? I know of Jesus, Lazarus, and John the Baptist.

Jesus is found in most of the NT, Lazarus is found in the Gospel of John, and John the Baptist is claimed to have risen by Jews and Herod in the Synoptics.

What other 1st century Jews are claimed to have risen? Sources are not limited to NT canon.

Comment: Matthew 27:52 says "The bodies of many holy people who had died were raised to life.". It's pretty certain that most of those would be Jews.

Comment: I forgot about that! Good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jesus raised the daughter of Jarius (a synagogue ruler). By the time Jesus got to the house of Jarius, his daughter had died:

> "He took her by the hand and said to her, "*Talitha koum!"* (which means "Little girl, I say to you, get up!").  Immediately the girl stood up and walked around (she was twelve years old). At this they were completely astonished" (Mark 6:41-42).

Thunderforge mentioned an incident (in Acts 20:7-12) where a young man called Eutychus was listening to Paul preach in an upstairs room late at night:

> Seated in a window was a young man named Eutychus, who was sinkinginto a deep sleep as Paul talked on andon.  When he was sound asleep, he fell to the ground from the third storey and was picked up dead.  Paul went down, threw himself on the young man and put his arms around him. "Don't be alarmed," he said. "He's alive!" Then he went upstairs again... The people took the young man home alive and were greatly comforted."

There is also an incident in Acts 9:36-43 where Peter raised Tabitha, a disciple, from the dead.

I am unaware of any reference in the Bible to John the Baptist being resurrected. Where did that idea come from?

Of course, the difference between the resurrection of Jesus and any other person is that Jesus still lives, whereas Lazarus and the daughter of Jarius died later.  Likewise with the dead who came to life after the resurrection of Jesus (Matthew 27:52-53), as mentioned by D J Clayworth.

Comment: The idea that John the Baptist had been resurrected was the erroneous thought of Herod the tetrarch (who got a fourth of Herod the Great's region to rule). Upon hearing of Jesus' miracles, this son of Herod the Great was frightened, supposing that although he had had John the Baptist beheaded, John had been resurrected. Not so. Matthew 14:1.

Comment: Luke also records that some other than Herod thought John the Baptist rose. Luke 9:7

Comment: Does the one who Paul raised from the dead after he fell out a window count?

Comment: Yes, Thunderforge, I would say Eutychus not only 'counts' but could be viewed as the patron saint of sermon sleepers!

Comment: There's also the son of the widow in Nain (Lk 7:11–17); that village isn't far from Capernaum, so they're all likely to be Gallilean Jews.